# RegEx For Validating Media Files

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some MP3 files that are named with a particular syntax, for example:

> 1 - Sebastian Ingrosso - Calling (Feat. Ryan Tedder)

I have written a small program in C# that reads the Track, Artist and Title from the ID3 tags. What i would like to do is write a regex expression that can validate that the files are in fact named with the syntax listed above.

So i have a class called song:

```
class Song
{
    //Fields
    private string _filename;
    private string _title;
    private string _artist;


    //Properties
    public string Filename
    {
        get { return _filename;  }
        set { _filename = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title;  }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    public string Artist
    {
        get { return _artist;  }
        set { _artist = value; }
    }


    //Methods

    public bool Parse(string strfile)
    {
        bool CheckFile;

        Tags.ID3.ID3v1 Song = new Tags.ID3.ID3v1(strfile, true);
        Filename = Song.FileName;
        Title = Song.Title;
        Artist = Song.Artist;


        //Check File Name Formatting
        string RegexBuilder = @"\d\s-\s" + Artist + @"\s-\s" + Title;
        if (Regex.IsMatch(Filename, RegexBuilder))
        {
            CheckFile = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckFile = false;
        }
        return CheckFile;
     }
```

So it works, MOST OF THE TIME. The minute i have a (Feat. ) in the title it fails. The closest i could come up with is:

> \d\s-\s\Artist\s-\s.*

That's obviously not going to work as any text would pass the test. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify - you want a regex that will work with a `(Feat. xxx)` in the track as well?

Comment: Why exactly does it fail for “feat.”? Is that part not in the title ID3 tag?

Comment: Specify the format you want. Your question is not clear at all. <Track#>-<Artist>-<Title>[Featuring] ?

Comment: hey guys, sorry ive only been programming for a month i should have been more clear, i would like a regex that matches "1 - Sebastian Ingrosso - Calling (Feat. Ryan Tedder)" as well as songs that don't contain the (Feat. ****) so for example "1 - Pitbull - Back in Time"

Answer (score 1):

`\d\s-\s\Sebastian Ingrosso\s-\sCalling(\s\(Feat.*)?`

This works for both:

```
1 - Sebastian Ingrosso - Calling (Feat. Ryan Tedder)
1 - Sebastian Ingrosso - Calling
```

So:

```
string RegexBuilder = @"\d\s-\s" + Artist + @"\s-\s" + Title + "(\s\(Feat.*)?";
```

Should do the job

**It can be tried out** here:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: when i use this regex pattern on a song i get an error "parsing "\d\s-\sFun\s-\sWe Are Young (Feat. Janelle Mo(\s\(Feat.*)?" - Not enough )'s."